# What is really happening when I call a function?

Tags: javascript

This might be a simple question but I've been thinking lately. I've tried researching for the answer but I have yet to find a satisfactory one.
Basically, what's happening behind the scene when I call a function? Say:-

```
function sayHello(){
    console.log('hello');
}
sayHello(); //what's happening here?
```

I know that doing `sayHello.call();` or `sayHello.apply();` is the same thing as doing `sayHello();` but is there any more information on what's happening underneath or is it behind the mysterious native code?

Comment: Is your question about the differences between call and apply and probably their effect on the context(aka this)

Comment: heh, well there is http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf - but `console.log` is native code because it's provided by the browser as a host api.

Comment: What are you looking for?  A new scope object is created.  An arguments object is created and put into the scope object with any arguments passed to the function.  Any local variables are put into the scope object, a reference to the next line of code is pushed onto the execution stack (so the interpreter knows where to go when the function returns), the `this` pointer is set as appropriate and then execution is transferred to the code of the function.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, that's more or less what I'm looking for. I'm guessing that's all happening behind the native code?

Comment: @shriek - it's happening in the JS interpreter.  That's one of its jobs (to manage function calls) and yes it is native code.

Comment: @jfriend00 ahh. I wanted to know this information cause I wanted to call a specific function whenever any `function` is called.

Comment: @Hamish :D. I'll go through that some day.

Comment: @shriek: no, that's not possible unless you modify the interpreter to change how the `[[Call]]` internal function runs.

Comment: @Dalorzo— *this* isn't context, it's just one parameter of an [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the things the interpreter does to make a JS function call:

- A new scope object is created. An arguments object is created and put
  into the scope object with any arguments passed to the function in
  it.
- Any local variables in the new function are put into the scope
  object.
- A reference to the next line of code is pushed onto the execution
  stack (so the interpreter knows where to go when the function
  returns).
- The this pointer is set as appropriate.
- Execution is transferred to the code of the function.

This is managed by the internals of the JS interpreter (one of its many jobs) which is likely native code.

---

If you want to call function `B()` anytime function `A()` is called, you can replace function `A()` with your own proxy which calls function `B()` and then calls the original `A()`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should have been more clear on how the interpreter is working on function call rather than confuse people. 


And because I have no clue on which function is being called is why I wanted to make a global "trap" function so that I can track it's stack.

Comment: @shriek - I don't know exactly what problem you're trying to solve, but perhaps you just want to step through your code line by line in the debugger and watch exactly what it does.